# Livecode, mobileComposeHtmlMail image error in html

Tags: html, email, attachment, livecode

We are trying to attach an image in an HTML email and use `mobileComposeHtmlMail` to send them on mobile devices. Here is the code. It sends the email, but the images are NOT attaching. We tried base64 encoding, but that did not work.

```
-->HTML Code



-- Put image cid

put "<img src='cid:myimagecid'/> " after tBody



-->HTML Code



-- Get image binary data

put getGraphImage() into tChartImg

-- Put image binary data into attachment

put tChartImg into tAttachment[1]["data"]



-- Put image type into attachment

put "image/png" into tAttachment[1][["type"]



-- Put image name into attachment

put "myimagecid.png" into tAttachment[1][["name"]



put "myimagecid" into tAttachment[1][["cid"]



-- Pass tAttachment parameter to mobileComposeHtmlMail function

mobileComposeHtmlMail tSubject, tSendTo, , ,tBody, tAttachment
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please add that into your question.

Comment: That doesn't show error, but on email the image doesn't displaying. Shows broken image. I have tried also just put URL in image src and again the same - image doesn't displaying.

Comment: Maybe the error is suppressed or logged? Do you have logs for this e.g. via the Apache logs? Or can you run the code in a console context to watch for errors in stdout/stderr?